# JBoss Forge x Spring Boot

Tags: java

Qual diferença entre JBoss Forge x Spring Boot?

Quando utilizar um ou outro?

Existe algum "TomCat Forge" por exemplo?

Ou são coisas diferentes?

Answer (score 3):

Bom dia, acredito que já tenha a resposta da pergunta.

**[JBoss Forge](https://forge.jboss.org/)**

O Forge é um projeto da comunidade JBoss utilizado para auxiliar na construção de aplicações Java, possui o diferencial de gerar código através de instruções de linha de comando. É capaz de criar estrutura de pastas, classes, métodos, atributos e etc. Possui suporte para gerar telas CRUD automaticamente a partir do banco ou deendpoints de uma API.

Ele ajuda também em configurações como por exemplo: se o desenvolvedor deseja utilizar uma versão específica do JPA, com um comando do forge ele adiciona as dependências, classes de configurações e códigos de exemplo. Além de ajudar a codificar, o Forge pode compilar e executar a aplicação utilizando os comandos e plugins (addons) específicos.

**[Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot)**

O Spring Boot possui a mesma temática, gera estrutura, código, configuração e etc. Ele utiliza as vantagens de desenvolvimento da comunidade Sring, poucos XML e possui uma forma otimizada de execução chamada de container embarcado, onde a aplicação é executada sem a necessidade de "deploy" em um app server (Tomcat, Wildfly e etc.).

**Conclusão**

São ferramentas de auxílio ao desenvolvimento semelhantes com enfoque distintos, para escolher qual delas utilizar, precisamos analisar o objetivo da solução.

Espero ajudar.